# Transferred my website from MAMP to a LAMP stack server. Why is my website not connecting to the database?

Tags: php, mysql, lamp, linode

I am new to servers and the command line, but I have successfully transfered my php files to the server and it appears that i have imported the mysql database successfully (at least i see it in /var/lib/mysql).  I am using Linode as my host, I am locally using MAC terminal to connect to a ubuntu linux server.

Could anyone explain what I may be missing or how I should properly set things up?

Comment: You're going to need to provide a lot more info about what errors you're seeing, et cetera - check the apache error log for PHP error output.

Comment: it appears that there are no errors in the php log.  and there's actually nothing in the database - i just imported the table structures.  should the php log keep a track of whether it connects to mysql?  if so there are no records of this in the log.

Comment: How do you know that your website isn't connecting to the database if you aren't getting any errors and the database is empty?

Comment: How did you transfer the database?  Did you just copy some files?

Comment: ok i'm going to reimport a database with data and structure.  i am using Sequel Pro and connecting with an SSH tunnel.  Where should I import the database to in the directory?  var/lib/mysql/?  or var/lib/mysql/mysql/?  or do i need to create a new database and then import into that db?

Comment: where to import depends on your mysql settings. I recommend you dump your data by mysqldump or something and import it to running DB, so you don't have to worry about where to copy your DB data files.